# Angular service to share data - Is this the correct approach?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hello Angular Gurus,

I'm using a service to share data between two controllers. I'm sharing data between BankController and CreateBankController.

What I observe is that the CreateBankController initializes and creates an instance of the Popup Service (sharedservice). Since its a singleton, the Popup Service does not instantiate every time, so it' now holds stale data in the CreateBankController. I can see the data getting set into my Popup Service, but CreateBankController has a stale instance of Popup Service that was created the first time. I suppose since its a singleton that is the expected behavior.

Couple of queries with the approach I have taken

1. Firstly, Is this the correct approach to take to share data between two controllers? Please check bank. create.controller.js for the complete code. Is there a better approach to take?
2. Should I have a broadcast method to broadcast changes to my Popup Service whenever I set it. Is this the approach to take? Will the Popup Service instance in CreateBankController be updated with the changed data if I call into the broadcast method? Appreciate if you could show me through changes in plunker or any code samples as I am trying to understand the broadcast method implementation.

**PLUNKER LINK**
[**Plunker Code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fCt83O?p=preview)

Steps

1. Create the Bank Tab, choose any of the first few orders' bank rows.
2. Click edit link, first time works fine.
3. Select any other row , you  will see stale data reflecting.

   ```
   (function () {
   'use strict';

   angular
   .module('myApp')
   .factory('PopupService', PopupService);

   function PopupService() {
   var popupInstance = {};
   var objectToEdit = {};
   var service = {
       addObjecToEdit : addObjecToEdit,
       getObjectToEdit: getObjectToEdit,
       setPopupInstance: setPopupInstance,
       getPopupInstance : getPopupInstance,
       showPopup: showPopup,
       hidePopup: hidePopup

   };
   return service;

   function setPopupInstance(instance){
       popupInstance = instance;
   }

   function getPopupInstance(){
       return popupInstance;
   }

   //Functions
   function addObjecToEdit(pObjectToEdit){
     console.log("Adding object to Edit in Popup Service : " + JSON.stringify(pObjectToEdit));
       objectToEdit = pObjectToEdit;
   }

   function getObjectToEdit() {
     console.log("Getting object to Edit in Popup Service : " + JSON.stringify(objectToEdit));
       return objectToEdit;
   }

   function showPopup(){
       popupInstance.showPopup();
   }

   function hidePopup(){
       popupInstance.hidePopup();
   }
   }
   }());`
   ```